# pyspark udf to process multiple rows at a time

Tags: pyspark

Reading this blog:
[Introducing Pandas UDF for PySpark](https://databricks.com/blog/2017/10/30/introducing-vectorized-udfs-for-pyspark.html)

I acknowledged that using `@udf` processes one row at a time, but using `@pandas_udf` processes multiple rows at a time (as pandas) and is much faster.

Why is it necessary to convert the spark dataframe into pandas dataframe in order to achieve this (processing multiple rows at a time)? Can't `@udf` take just a part of the spark dataframe at a time and avoid this conversion? Is it because spark dataframes are not optimized to process multiple rows at a time like pandas? If so, why?

Thanks~